# Linux reboots on shut down

Tags: 16.04, wireless, broadcom, acpi

I have a dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.

Shutting down ubuntu reboots the device and I have to launch windows (which I have set default in the grub boot list) and shut down my device from windows os.

Tried some tweaks found online:

- adding `acpi=noirq` in the kernel arguments `/etc/default/grub` and then updating grub.
- checked wake on lan feature but it was off.
- installed `laptop-mode-tools` but that didn't seem to solve the problem either.
- tried wifi on/off before shutting down.
- various shutdown commands from terminal.

apparantly, none of them seem to work.
Also, wifi is showing issues due to this reboot issue (works fine on windows).

The same happens when I install kali linux.

Running `lspci` shows this: https://pastebin.com/4KLzYMSf

Wireless info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rqj4PW9VBY/

Device is acer with nvidia graphics support, if that's relevant.

**Edit: 
Update to the post-**
After playing with the options, this setting seems to solve both reboot and wifi issues-

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi=force”`

which I modified to-

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”acpi=force quiet splash”`

But I can't figure out why.

[Source](https://www.unixmen.com/fix-shutdown-power-computer-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: What shutdown commands have you tried?

Comment: never mind, I found a solution after a lot of homework, I'll update the post.